# Derivations using rules and axoims

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am using the text Propositional and Predicate Calculus : A Model of Argument and I have a create a derivation for the following:

$(p \rightarrow q)$, $( \lnot p \rightarrow r)$, $\lnot(\lnot q \rightarrow r)$ $\vdash$ $\lnot \lnot p$

I can start with:

$\lnot(\lnot q \rightarrow r)$

$\lnot r$

$( \lnot p \rightarrow r)$

$\lnot \lnot p $

I was told I could use these steps but I am not sure which rules or axioms were used.

Comment: I made some edits. Could you please take a look and see whether that was what you meant?

Comment: See your previous post: [derivations-from-propositional-and-predicate-calculus-a-model-of-argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479746/derivations-from-propositional-and-predicate-calculus-a-model-of-argument)

Comment: Again, use the def of $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ where now we have $\Gamma = \{ (p→q), (¬p→r), ¬(¬q→r) \}$ and $\phi$ is $¬¬p$.

Answer (score 0):

> $\lnot(\lnot q \rightarrow r)$
>
> $\lnot r$

To prove $\lnot r$, assume $r$ and look for a contradiction.  $r$ gives you $\text{anything} \to r$ which contradicts $\lnot( \lnot q \to r)$.

> $( \lnot p \rightarrow r)$
>
> $\lnot \lnot p $

Same thing again.  To prove $\lnot \lnot p$, assume $\lnot p$ and look for a contradiction.  $\lnot p$ gives you $r$, but that contradicts the $\lnot r$ from the prior step, so a contradiction is found.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMgQF.jpg  Here are the rules provided for us to use

Comment: I need help understanding which rules or axioms were used. Did they skip some steps?

Comment: @Badapple Proofs in that particular system are notoriously difficult!  Have you done any proofs in this system (or any proof system) before?

Comment: @Badapple What Bram28 said is correct.  Without a lot of Lemmas, the proof you are asking for would be a page long at least.

Comment: no, I have not.